# Unable to build android app in react-native after google-play-service update

Tags: react-native

I am getting the error after running react-native run-android --

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

```js
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
Android resource linking failed
 Output:  /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:293: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
 /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:293: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
 error: failed linking references.

 Command: /../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/5a5e4d34c69b7e8b3552937157493c40/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
         /../../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
         --manifest\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
         -o\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
         -R\
         @/../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
         --auto-add-overlay\
         --java\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
         --custom-package\
         com.app\
         -0\
         apk\
         --output-text-symbols\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
         --no-version-vectors
 Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
 Output:  /../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawee-1.10.0.aar/ac1ce9b9fcfb8b8c996ede4ab043d5d6/res/values/values.xml:3:5-58:857: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

 /../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawee-1.10.0.aar/ac1ce9b9fcfb8b8c996ede4ab043d5d6/res/values/values.xml:3:5-58:857: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

 error: failed linking references.
 Command: /../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/5a5e4d34c69b7e8b3552937157493c40/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
         /../../Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
         --manifest\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
         -o\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
         -R\
         @/../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
         --auto-add-overlay\
         --java\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
         --custom-package\
         com.app\
         -0\
         apk\
         --output-text-symbols\
         /../../bitbucket/app/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
         --no-version-vectors
 Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https:/help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
73 actionable tasks: 72 executed, 1 up-to-date

I have already updated the sdk versions and react-native-device-info version. Still facing the issue.

dependencies : app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies 
{
    compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    compile project(':react-native-fused-location')
    compile project(':react-native-android-open-settings')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript 
{
    ext 
    {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    }
    repositories 
    {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies 
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}



subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: Try changing the 'compile' to 'implementation' in dependencies.
compile is deprecated

Eg: - Change 'compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')' to 'implementation project(':react-native-wheel-picker')'.

Comment: Also change targetSdkVersion and supportLibVersion to 27 and 27.0.0 respectively in android/build.gradle 'buildscript'.

Comment: Already tried. But not working.

Comment: This is weird, your files say your compileSdkVersion is 28 but effectively 27 is used (android-27/android.jar is used). You need to figure out why this is happening and then make it use 28 instead.